# Display Multiple PHP Queries

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to display multiple queries (they can't be combined into one large query, at least I don't think so) together in a webpage. I'll explain a little about the queries to give an idea of the problem. I have a database in MySQL with 3 question tables of the same format linked to a response table via a classid. The response table is linked to an instructor table via an instructorid. I need to display a table showing all 3 question scores for each record existing for an instructor, with each table followed by some text indicating which question had the highest value as well as the least. I created a `uniontbl` view in MySQL which is a union query with fields `ClassID`, `Average` and `TableName`. What I have so far is:

```
$query2 = "SELECT `tbl_instructor`.`FirstName`, 
                `tbl_instructor`.`LastName`, 
                `tbl_term`.`TermID`, 
                `tbl_ucourse`.`Abbreviation`, 
                `tbl_ucourse`.`Series`, 
                `tbl_uquestion01`.`Average` AS `Q1`, 
                `tbl_uquestion02`.`Average` AS `Q2`,
                `tbl_uquestion03`.`Average` AS `Q3`
            FROM `tbl_instructor`
            LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_uresponse` ON `tbl_instructor`.`InstructorID` = `tbl_uresponse`.`InstructorID` 
            LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_ucourse` ON `tbl_uresponse`.`CourseID` = `tbl_ucourse`.`CourseID` 
            LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_Term` ON `tbl_UResponse`.`TermID` = `tbl_Term`.`TermID` 
            LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_uquestion01` ON `tbl_uresponse`.`ClassID` = `tbl_uquestion01`.`ClassID` 
            LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_uquestion02` ON `tbl_uresponse`.`ClassID` = `tbl_uquestion02`.`ClassID` 
            LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_uquestion03` ON `tbl_uresponse`.`ClassID` = `tbl_uquestion03`.`ClassID` 
            WHERE CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' (', UserID, ')') = '{$instructor}'";

$query3 = "SELECT `tbl_instructor`.`FirstName`, 
                    `tbl_instructor`.`LastName`,
                    `uniontbl`.`ClassID`, 
                    `uniontbl`.`TableName`,
                    `tbl_uresponse`.`InstructorID` 
                FROM `tbl_Instructor`
                LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_uresponse` ON `tbl_instructor`.`InstructorID` = `tbl_uresponse`.`InstructorID`
                LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`uniontbl` ON `tbl_uresponse`.`ClassID` = `uniontbl`.`ClassID`
                WHERE CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' (', UserID, ')') = '{$instructor}'
                ORDER BY `uniontbl`.`Average` DESC
                LIMIT 1";

$query4 = "SELECT `tbl_instructor`.`FirstName`, 
                    `tbl_instructor`.`LastName`,
                    `uniontbl`.`ClassID`, 
                    `uniontbl`.`TableName`,
                    `tbl_uresponse`.`InstructorID` 
                FROM `tbl_Instructor`
                LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`tbl_uresponse` ON `tbl_instructor`.`InstructorID` = `tbl_uresponse`.`InstructorID`
                LEFT JOIN `undergrad`.`uniontbl` ON `tbl_uresponse`.`ClassID` = `uniontbl`.`ClassID`
                WHERE CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' (', UserID, ')') = '{$instructor}'
                ORDER BY `uniontbl`.`Average` ASC
                LIMIT 1";


$result2 = mysqli_query($query2);

$result3 = mysqli_query($query3);

$result4 = mysqli_query($query4);



while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo"<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Q1</th>";
        echo "<th>Q2</th>";
        echo "<th>Q3</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Q1'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Q2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row2['Q3'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo"<br>";
        echo "</table>";

        while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))
            {
                echo $row3['TableName'];
            }

        echo "<br>";

        while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4))
            {
                echo $row4['TableName'];
            }

        echo "<br>";

    }
```

So, how I've tried to tackle the problem is using the second and third queries to determine which questions had the highest and lowest score from the `uniontbl` view and displaying that after each table containing the question scores. The problem is that the second and third queries ONLY display after the first table (or record) and do not show at all after that. I have a feeling that the problem lies in the actual queries themselves but I can't think of another way to solve the problem. P.S. I know my code isn't the best (echoing HTML and such) but I'm just trying to get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

After you print the first row of `$result2`, you fetch all the rows of `$result3` and `$result4`. So after you print the second row of `$result2`, there's nothing left to fetch from the second and third queries.

Since the second and third queries use `LIMIT 1`, there's just one row for each of them. You could fetch them each once, and then display that row after each row of the first query. But I'm not sure why you need to display the same thing multiple times. Maybe you should just show the output of these two queries once, at the beginning or end, rather than after each row.

Also, do you really want to create a whole new table for each row of `$result2`? Usually each row is just a row in one big table, not a separate table with just one row for each row from the DB.

Comment: The reason each record is to be displayed as a separate table is because each is associated with a different class. Of course, the questions scores also vary by record, so the purpose of the second and third queries is to identify which question had the highest score, and which had the lowest for each class (or record). This seems a little pointless (you can just visually determine this), but the next step will be to display certain text based on the which question had the highest/lowest scores.

Comment: But the second and third queries are not returning per-class information. They're just returning the highest and lowest score for the instructor.

Comment: Just a quick note, the second and third queries do not return the highest/lowest scores, they return the name of the table (in other words, which question) have the highest/lowest scores. Any suggestions as to how to have them do this per-class?...

Comment: A simple way would be to run a new second and third query after each row of the first query, inserting the class name returned by the first query into these two queries. You could also do it with a complicated join, to combine all 3 queries into one.

Comment: I have been racking my brain trying to join the three queries into one with no avail because that seemed like the simpler solution to me at first. If I want to approach the problem with the first method, how do I insert the class name returned by the first query actively? The number of records for each instructor varies...

Comment: Which column in the first query is the class name? And where would it go into the second query?

Comment: If I were to add the class name to the first query:
`tbl_uresponse`.`ClassID`. I don't think any additional joins are needed. Then the question again arises, how is this classid fed to the second and third queries?